"RETURNING ID" in Spark SQL similiar to Postgres
I wish to create an ID column in Spark SQL which is auto-incrementing. Since it is not directly possible, I tried to search a method which is similar to Postgres's RETURNING ID
I tried going with the monotonically_increasing_id(), but it is only applicable after a table has been created and then assigning the ID to the table.
I wish to have a method which either gives me the latest ID of the column and then I increment it while inserting data; or I have a method to auto-increment the ID column.

What do you mean by monotonically_increasing_id is only applicable after a table has been created?

It means that it once a table has been created, this function can be used to assign increasing ID to the existing rows only. If I had a new row without the ID column, it will not assign an ID to this new row automatically
